# Angular Material: How to close all mat-dialogs and sweet-alerts on logout

Tags: angular, angular-material, ng-bootstrap, sweetalert2

I wanted to close all my dialog's (mat-dialog, bootstrap modals & sweet alerts) on logout in Angular. This is how it was done in AngularJS (version 1.5):

```
function logout() {
  //hide $mdDialog modal
  angular.element('.md-dialog-container').hide();

  //hide any open $mdDialog modals & backdrop
  angular.element('.modal-dialog').hide();
  angular.element('md-backdrop').remove();

  //hide any open bootstrap modals & backdrop
  angular.element('.inmodal').hide();
  angular.element('.fade').remove();

  //hide any sweet alert modals & backdrop
  angular.element('.sweet-alert').hide();
  angular.element('.sweet-overlay').remove();
}
```

How can I do this in Angular? Using `$('.mat-dialog-container')` or `$('.inmodal')` does't give me an option to do `hide()` or `close()`

I tried doing this, but I wan't able to get the element reference:

```
import { ElementRef, Injectable, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogContainer, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

export class MyClass
{
  @ViewChild('.mat-dialog-container') _matDialog: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('.mat-dialog-container') _matDialogRef:MatDialogRef<MatDialog>;

  constructor() { }

  function logout()
  {
    //access the dialogs here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is what i have done to close any open `mat-dialog` throughout the application:

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';

export class myClass {

constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialog) {
}

logOut()
{
  this.dialogRef.closeAll();
}

}
```

If you would like to close only a specific dialog you can loop through `dialogRef.openDialogs` and close the respective dialog using `close()`

This is how you can close any open/active sweet alert dialog:

```
const sweetAlertCancel = document.querySelector('.swal2-cancel') as HTMLElement;

if (sweetAlertCancel) {
    sweetAlertCancel.click(); //only if cancel button exists
}

const sweetAlertConfirm = document.querySelector('.swal2-confirm') as HTMLElement;

if (sweetAlertConfirm) {
   sweetAlertConfirm.click(); //if cancel doesn't exist , confirm is the equivalent for Ok button
}
```

Unlike `material-dialog` there is no method available to close or hide all open sweet alert dialog's. This is what i'm able to do so far.

Comment: You are right, but your variable name is misleading. MatDialog is the dialog service itself. When you open a dialog that's when you get a dialogRef. :)

Comment: like @Totati said, `private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>` is usually `dialogRef` because it is a reference and `private matDialog: MatDialog` is an instance of `MatDialog`. So use `this.matDialog.closeAll();`.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone looking for an answer, if method `.closeAll()` is not available on `DialogRef` (e.g. if using newer `@angular/material` components):

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';

constructor(matDialog: MatDialog) {…}

logout() {
    this.matDialog.closeAll();
}
```

Comment: ..and if you want to do something after all dialog is closed you should use `this.matDialog.afterAllClosed.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(() => doSomething())`