# Angular Interceptor and dialogs

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, ondestroy, httpinterceptor

So we have an HTTP Interceptor that will prompt the user with a dialog (requiring a button press).

My question is how do I allow my UI Component to interface with the Http Interceptor to close this dialog if I wanted to.  We are currently capturing BACK/FWD button presses and prompting if unsaved data is found.  At the same time the back end service could have prompted with a dialog and the user simply wants to go back to his last page.  That dialog is still up and I can't find a solution for how to close it.  I've added a dialogRef to the HTTP inteceptor and a close() method to close it but I'm not seeing anyone who actually does anything like this?

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements but if your goal is to close all dialogs in an interceptor you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602525/6236935

Comment: 1. If every step have a separate component, so put condition in ngDestroy.
2. create observable function in service and maintain state, according to state pass check on that particular component and trigger  this.dialogRef.closeAll(); event to close the dialog.